# array of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the array add up to k

Tags: javascript

```
findSums(arr, k) {
   let hashMap
   hashMap = {};
   for (let value of arr) {
      if (hashMap[value]) {
         return true;
      } else {
         hashMap[k - value] = true
      };
   }
   return false;
}
```

I am perplexed a bit how this function works. `hashMap[k - value]` how exactly is that bit deducing a sum of 2 integers in `arr` with k?

Comment: As a suggestion, for both this and any other relatively small, simple bits of code you might struggle to understand: try to run through it one line at a time, with a sample input. This often shows you exactly how things work - and I think would help you understand here, better than any written explanation could.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I stepped through it and it was still nebulous, try it for yourself in dev tools. I set a breakpoint on each statement.

Comment: For each iteration over the array-- assuming the value hasn't been encountered previously, which is the case for first iteration-- this code will subtract the array value from `k`, and mark that resulting value as `true`.  Then if that resulting value is subsequently encountered by the loop, the `if` check for `hashMap[value]` returns `true`, and the algorithm knows there's a value in the array that the current iteration's value can combine with to make `k`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start reading it from the `else` block, then the `if` block.

What `hashMap[k - value] = true` does is keep track of what number we will need to get to `k` using the current item `value` of the array.

For example, if `k` is `11` and the current item `value` is `7`, then `hashMap` will become `{ "4": true }`, meaning that we are looking for a `4` (because `7 + 4 == 11`). If the next `value` is `3`, then `hashMap` becomes `{ "4": true, "8": true }`, meaning we are looking for either `4` or `8` at this point, ...

Now, we get back to the `if` block, that block simply checks if the current `value` is one of the numbers that we are looking for (the `4` or the `8` from the example above). If so, we return `true` immediately as we already have found two numbers that add up to `k` so no need to keep searching. Note that for the first iteration of the loop, this `if` block can't be entered anyway because `hashMap` is still an empty `{}`.